# Why am I getting a RuntimeWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, runtime

I am using a dataframe looking like this:
[image]

with those dtypes:

```
priceNum                     float64
volumeNum                    float64
deliveryStart    datetime64[ns, UTC]
execution        datetime64[ns, UTC]
buySell                       object
dtype: object
```

I want to peform a simple calculation using the `volumeNum` column. Therefore I am splitting the dataframe into slices since I want one value for every deliveryStart:

```
dfs_dict={k: v for k, v in allOurTrades30min.groupby("deliveryStart")}

for key in dfs_dict:
    sort_df(dfs_dict[key])  
    remaining=calc_remaining(dfs_dict[key])
    
    if remaining<0:
        dfs_dict[key]["weightedOpening"]= (-calc_weighted(dfs_dict[key][dfs_dict[key]["buySell"]=="S"], remaining))
        dfs_dict[key]["remaining"]= remaining
    else:
        dfs_dict[key]["weightedOpening"]= calc_weighted(dfs_dict[key][dfs_dict[key]["buySell"]=="B"], remaining)
        dfs_dict[key]["remaining"]= remaining
```

I am getting this Warning: `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:45: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars` and if I look at one of the calculated dataframes via `dfs_dict[list(dfs_dict.keys())[1]]` it looks like this:
[image]

I found out that the problem is occuring within the `calc_remaining()` funciton which looks like this:

```
def calc_remaining(df):
    remaining=0.0
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i]["buySell"] == "B":
            remaining = remaining + df.iloc[i]["volumeNum"]
        elif df.iloc[i]["buySell"] == "S": 
            remaining = remaining - df.iloc[i]["volumeNum"]
    
    remaining = round(remaining,3)
    return remaining
```

I just don't see the problem.

**EDIT**

Some of the dataframes are completly fine. If I concat them all together it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You are trying to add a number and a NaN, which is by definition "Not a Number".

Comment: @CrispyHoliday can you tell me where? calc_weighted() returns a float value as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is coming from adding a number to a NaN.  You can do a broad sweep to fix this with [.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) if you cannot otherwise prevent a NaN from populating those cells.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand. Check under "EDIT", for some dataframes the calculation worked completly fine.